# Is there any api to get 3D maps from google maps Api?

Tags: google-maps

Can we get the 3D maps from the Google Maps API ?
i need to get the 3d  model of any particular place just like the NYC 3d modedl.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the 3D Maps feature is not yet available from the Google Maps Platform - Maps JavaScript API.

But, we do have an existing feature request for this in our Google Issue Tracker. To express your interest and to subscribe you to its latest updates, I suggest that you star this entry: https://issuetracker.google.com/35821626

In the mean time, you may want to consider checking out the [45° Imagery](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#45DegreeImagery) and see if this will fit your use case. You could also find a code sample of this service [here](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/aerial-simple).